# Why file_exists() function doesn't work correctly?

Tags: php, html, function, path, directory

Here is my code:

```
<?php $filename = $var.'p_folder/'.sub_replace('?','',$page).'/images/default.png'; ?>
<img src  = "<?php echo $filename; ?>"
     title= "<?php echo file_exists($filename) ? 'exists' : 'not exist'; ?>" 
>
```

My code shows the image as well, but `file_exists()` returns false *(I mean "not exist" prints)*.. Why?

Actually that's pretty much odd for me .. because I can see the image on the web, so it means the image exists on the directory, but why  `file_exists()` cannot find it?

Comment: Have you tried not embedding it, instead you first set the $filename and embed that variable on the <img> element?

Comment: You should try <?php $filename = $var.'p_folder/'.sub_replace('?','',$page).'/images/default.png'; ?><img src="<?php
echo $filename;
?>" title="<?php file_exists($filename) ? 'exists' : 'not exist'; ?>" >

Comment: `file_exists` check file path not file url

Answer (score 2):

file_exists() needs to use a file path on the hard drive, not a URL. So you should have something more like:

```
$thumb_name = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'images/abcd.jpg';

if(file_exists($thumb_name)) {
   //your code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

check your image path and then sever name & document root